# Why doesn't API mode work with two XBee units?

Tags: xbee

I have two XBee Pro Series 1 units. Both of them are in AP=2 mode (API mode). I have followed the instructions outlined under the "Series 1" section in *[XBee Configuration](http://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/wiki/XBeeConfiguration)*. I try to execute ["ZnetSenderExample.java"](http://xbee-api.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/com/rapplogic/xbee/examples/zigbee/ZNetSenderExample.java) and I can see it tries to send out a very simple "Xbee" string.

However, I keep getting timeouts on the receiving end saying it never gets any data.

Addtionally, I attempted the Unicast example on [this page](http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl?id=2184) and found the same behavior. It does not work in X-CTU when in API mode.

I am using firmware 10EC.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are the nodes on the same network?  When you look at them in X-CTU, do they share the same operating network settings (channel, PAN ID)?  Have you installed the API mode firmware, instead of the AT mode (sometimes called transparent serial) firmware?

Have you tried any of the [examples on Digi's site](http://examples.digi.com/), to confirm that the units are configured correctly?

Comment: Yes they are on the same channel and have the same Pan ID.  But I don't think I have the API mode firmware (as opposed to AT mode). Where can I get that?

Comment: My mistake -- the Series 1 modules have a single firmware build that supports by AT mode and API mode.  It's the Series 2 modules that have separate builds for each mode.